# How to track motion of object in video and get coordinates C#

Tags: c#, video

I am wondering how to compare frames to each other with threshhold, rectangle, blobcounter and erosion filters and get the coordinates of an object in the frame, then send that to a file as a variable.  How would I do this?

Comment: I havevtried using blob counter to track coordinates but i have no idea what placeholders to use or an efficient algorithm for doing that.  Or I could do something sneaky and rewrite the rectangles to the file and track colored pixels, but again, no idea for aglorithm or placeholder values that it returns.

Comment: Have you tried using an [opencv port for c#](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)?